# UITabBarContoller --> UISplitViewContoller

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5, ios-simulator

I want to show full screen view controller from `UISplitViewController` detail view controller. But I want `UITabBar` still to be visible. When I `presentViewController` it will hide my `UITabBar`. Can anyone suggest me the flow?

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the `modalPresentationStyle` of the detail view controller?  (Especially, `UIModalPresentationCurrentContext` ...though I think the result depends on which controller calls `presentViewController`.)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to nest your `UIViewController` in a `UINavigationController`.

Then instead of

```
[someViewController presentViewController: anotherViewController];
```

you have to call

```
[someNavigationController presentViewController:anotherViewController];
```

this will do the trick.

Note that it will add the `anotherViewController` at the top of the stack of `viewControllers`.

to remove it just call `dismissViewController` on the navigation controller!